# MySQL duration for 9 rows, that's my code

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(b.checktime,"%Y-%m-%d") AS dtDate,
   case when (
   SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.checktime,'%H:%i:%s')
   FROM checkinout a 
   WHERE a.checktype='0'
   and a.userid=1
   and DATE_FORMAT(a.checktime,'%Y-%m-%d')=DATE_FORMAT(b.checktime,'%Y-%m-%d')
   LIMIT 1)
   is not NULL 
   then
   (
   SELECT
   DATE_FORMAT(a.checktime,'%H:%i:%s')
   FROM checkinout a 
   WHERE a.checktype='0'
   and a.userid=1
   and DATE_FORMAT(a.checktime,'%Y-%m-%d')=DATE_FORMAT(b.checktime,'%Y-%m-%d')
  LIMIT 1
  ) 
  else 'N/A' END
  AS Chkin
  from checkinout b
  where
  DATE_FORMAT(b.checktime,"%m")='06' AND
  DATE_FORMAT(b.checktime,"%Y")='2019' AND
  DATE_FORMAT(b.checktime,"%w")!='0' AND . 
  DATE_FORMAT(b.checktime,"%w")!='6' AND .  
  DATE_FORMAT(b.checktime,"%Y-%m-%d") not in 
  (select date_s from wend)
  GROUP BY dtDate 
  ORDER BY dtDate DESC
```

> Affected rows: 0 Found rows: 9 Warnings: 0 Duration for 1 query: 25.665 sec.

what's wrong with this query, for 9 rows need 25.665 seconds

Thanks

Comment: The biggest bottleneck is probably the correlated condition in the subquery (`DATE_FORMAT(a.checktime,'%Y-%m-%d')=DATE_FORMAT(b.checktime,'%Y-%m-%d')`) which cannot use an index.

Comment: Mr. Paul Spiegel - Solved,yeah, thats worked, first i colleg the date for loop the query, i change like this,
(DATE_FORMAT(a.checktime,'%Y-%m-%d')=paramter_dates), Thanks sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without understanding the purpose of the query, it can be rewritten to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date(b.checktime) AS dtDate,
    coalesce((
        SELECT time(a.checktime)
        FROM checkinout a
        WHERE a.checktype = '0'
          and a.userid = 1
          and date(a.checktime) = date(b.checktime)
        LIMIT 1
    ), 'N/A') AS Chkin
from checkinout b
where month(b.checktime) = 6
  AND year(b.checktime) = 2019
  AND weekday(b.checktime) not in (5, 6) -- non weekend
  AND date(b.checktime) not in (select date_s from wend)
ORDER BY dtDate DESC
```

Though `GROUP BY` might perform better than `DISTINCT` - You should test both. However, the above query can be optimized to use indexes.

The outer condition `month(b.checktime) = 6 AND year(b.checktime) = 2019` can be rewritten to `b.checktime >= '2019-06-01' AND b.checktime < '2019-06-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH`. This way the engine should be able to use an index on `(checktime)`.

The condition `date(a.checktime) = date(b.checktime)` can be written as `a.checktime >= date(b.checktime) and a.checktime <  date(b.checktime) + INTERVAL 1 DAY`. Here I suggest one of the following indexes: `(checktype, userid, checktime)`, `(userid, checktype, checktime)` or `(userid, checktime)`.

And for `date(b.checktime) not in (select date_s from wend)` it might be better to use an "anti-join".

So here is the final query, which I would try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date(b.checktime) AS dtDate,
    coalesce((
        SELECT time(a.checktime)
        FROM checkinout a
        WHERE a.checktype = '0'
          and a.userid = 1
          and a.checktime >= date(b.checktime)
          and a.checktime <  date(b.checktime) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
        LIMIT 1
    ), 'N/A') AS Chkin
from checkinout b
LEFT JOIN wend w ON w.date_s = date(b.checktime)
where b.checktime >= '2019-06-01'
  AND b.checktime <  '2019-06-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
  AND weekday(b.checktime) not in (5, 6) -- non weekend
  AND w.date_s IS NULL
ORDER BY dtDate DESC
```